# Dataset that holds a list of pre-defined classes for each observation - in R

Tags: python, r

I'm new to R and need to keep a dataset that contains for each observation (let's say - a user) a list of classes (let's say events). 
for example - for each user_ID I hold a list of events, every event class contains the fields: name, time, type.

My question is - what is the optimal way to hold such data in R? I have several millions of such observations so I need to hold it in optimal manner (in terms of space).

In addition, after I decide how to hold it, I need create it from within python, as my original data is in python dict. What is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: you can have a python dict in r?

Comment: Let's see an example of a few items.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I edited the question. Hope now it's clarified.

Answer (score 3):

You can save your dict as a .csv using the `csv` module for Python.

```
mydict = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
with open("test.csv", "wb") as myfile:
    w = csv.writer(myfile)
    w.writerows(mydict.items())
```

Then just load it into R with `read.csv`.

Of course, depending on what your Python dict looks like, you may need some more post processing, but without a reproducible example it's hard to say what that would be.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is not the transfer itself, but I wonder what is the best way to hold a list of classes of type that I define (e.g. class A which has name, time, and type fields, for example) for every user. So I actually have 2 problems - what is the best way to hold it in R, and how can I create it by calling to R functions from within python. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3017075 You really have to give an example of your python dictionary if you want help with that